# Why is it returning this?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am trying to use lambda, but when I test it in the console, it returns `#<procedure:...esktop/Lab 4.rkt:105:2>`.

My code is

```
(define (comp f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

And my test code is

```
(comp (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 3)
```

For some reason, lambda is deferring the evaluation. Can someone please help?

Comment: `comp` takes two arguments, both functions. You are passing it a number as the second argument.

Comment: So I changed it to {(comp (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (y) (+ y 2)))} But it still returns the procedure. Shouldn't it return a number?

Comment: `comp` produces `(lambda (x) (f (g x)))`, which is a function, not a number. (The whole point of `comp` is to *comp*ose two functions to make a new function.)

Comment: Yes, lambda defers evaluation; that's what it does. The `lambda` operator wraps up expressions into a function object. Those expressions don't get evaluated until that function is called. Hidden lambdas are the basis for explicit lazy evaluation operators like `delay` and `force`.

Comment: The returned procedure will bomb if you call it, because you composed a function with the number 3, which isn't a function.  That is to say, for the `g` argument of `comp`, you passed `3`, but then the procedure returned by `comp` wants to call this: `(g x)` . I.e. `(3 x)`.

Answer (score 5):

`comp` takes two function arguments and returns a new function - their
composition:

```
(define (comp f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
;Value: comp
```

To test it, one has to call it on a *number*:

```
((comp (lambda (x) (+ x 1))
       (lambda (x) (+ x 2)))
 3)
;Value: 6
```